# Sharepoint 2013 and Node.js upload functionality for Sharepoint

Tags: node.js, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

As the question suggests we are looking for creating functionality of Upload/Download using Node.js. We have our destination in Sharepoint 2013 document library where we want to upload files.

First question is it possible to achieve this using node.js? If yes then how?

Any inputs will really be appreciated.

If anybody can explain what's node and how is it possible to communicate to another server for fetching or posting data(basically SharePoint)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't it your job to figure out the "*how*"?

Comment: Hi, I tried but Node.js do not seem to give the functionality at all. that's why I have this question. If you can confirm if this is possible then I can accept the negative marking.

Comment: Give what functionality? Node is just a RTE, there are loads of ready made libraries out there compliments of [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/). However, as with any other environment, it's up to you to actually build what you need.

Comment: so my question can be tweeked to ask if its possible to interact with Sharepoint? if yes then what do we need to do?

Comment: The user has asked the same question on SP.SE http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/128895/sharepoint-2013-and-node-js-upload-functionality-for-sharepoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have found out a way to do this. James was correct in pointing out that we need to do stuff we cannot just rely on built in classes. I had to edit a file present in the sharepoint lib folder. In the file I had to rewrite a method which was already present and tweak it to upload a file in a document library.

The file that I edited was "node_modules\node-sharepoint-rest\lib\CustomLists.coffee"
in this file there are methods which are making an ajax call to the sharepoint list. I edited the method which uploaded an attachement to a list item.

It was simple but had to dig in very much to make it work
Thanks for all the help.